# Borders causing alignment issues with divs and paragraphs

Tags: html, css, border

Very new to coding,

Mainly looking for `border` help and navbar issue of separation of words

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

  <head>
    <title>Rock Coast</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <header>
    <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/5bebu6mbl/Image_5_8_16_at_12_10_PM.jpgHome"></img>
    <div id="nav">
      <span><a href="#">Home</a></span>
      <span><a href="#"><button>Televeisions</button></a></span>
      <span><a href="#">Electronics</a></span>
      <span><a href="#">Services</a></span>
    </div>
  </header>

  </body>
  <div id="black">
    <h1> Something Occurs</h1>
    <p>Within this space is some text, or other graphical representations of things that this page displays</p>
  </div>
  <h1> Products </h1>
  <div id="parent">
    <span id="first"> <b>Product Name</b> </span>
    <span id="second"> <b>Product Name</b></span>
    <span id="third"> <b>Product Name</b> </span>
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    <pre>  
    This is a product
    description
    It takes up a few
    lines of space.
  <span style= "color:#b25a03;font-style:bold;"><strong>________________________ </strong></span> 

           Dimensions
    Product    might go
    Info:      here

               Another
    More       piece of
    Info:      data

  <span style= "color:#b25a03;font-style:bold;"><strong>________________________ </strong></span> 

     Buy it now!
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <pre>  
    This is a product
    description
    It takes up a few
    lines of space.
  <span style= "color:#b25a03;font-style:bold;"><strong>________________________ </strong></span> 

           Dimensions
    Product    might go
    Info:      here

               Another
    More       piece of
    Info:      data

  <span style= "color:#b25a03;font-style:bold;"><strong>________________________ </strong></span> 

     Buy it now!
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <pre>  
    This is a product
    description
    It takes up a few
    lines of space.
  <span style= "color:#b25a03;font-style:bold;"><strong>________________________ </strong></span> 

           Dimensions
    Product    might go
    Info:      here

               Another
    More       piece of
    Info:      data

  <span style= "color:#b25a03;font-style:bold;"><strong>________________________ </strong></span> 

     Buy it now!
    </pre>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  height: 5.5em;
  background: gray;
  color: Black;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
header {
  height: 5.5em;
  background: gray;
  color: Black;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
#nav {
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
}

#nav span a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background:white;
}



h1 {
  color: #e5780d;
  font-family: Courier;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-left:.5%;

}
p{margin-left:.5%;
  word-spacing:4px }

#black {
  margin: 3px solid black;
  word-spacing: 4px;
  margin:left:.75%;
}

h3 {
  color: #e5780d;
  font-family: Courier;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

span { vertical-align: baseline; }

#first { font-size:16px;
         margin-left:5.5%;
         }

#second {font-size:16px;
         margin-left:9.1%}

#third{font-size: 16px;
        margin-left:8.6%}

#left {
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background: #e5780d;
  width: 14%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:Bold;
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2.001%;
  color: white;
  background: #e5780d;
  width: 14%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:Bold
}

#right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 2.002%;
  background: #e5780d;
  width: 14%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:Bold;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjL3j8nr/4/)**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xjL3j8nr/4/

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick fork of your original [codepen](http://codepen.io/progdor/pen/zqbByb?editors=1100) just to see if I can help give you an idea of what you are doing. Short of a full tutorial the quick and dirty is that you need to be using proper markup and then grouping things intelligently as well.

I only built the nav for you, because short of doing the work for you I would like to see you learn a bit as well. The HTML looks something like:

```
  <header>
  <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/5bebu6mbl/Image_5_8_16_at_12_10_PM.jpgHome" />
    <nav role="navigation">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Televisions</a>
      <a href="#">Electronics</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
 <p>Content goes here</p>
</main>
```

And the basic CSS would be something like:

```
    body{
 background:black; 
}
header {
  background: #789;
  color: Black;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
header *{
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:4px;
}
nav {
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  top:-2rem;
  padding:.7rem 1rem;
  padding-right: 4rem;
}
nav a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding:.4rem .6rem;
}
nav a:hover{
  border:1px solid black;
  background:lightgray;
}
main{
  margin-top:10px;
  padding-top:.5rem;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:1rem;
  background:white;
}
```

Hopefully if you look at the codepen I did for you, you'll have at least a jumping off point and I can answer any specific questions you may have.

*** EDIT **
The html for the block elements I would probably do something like :

```
<section>
    <div>
      Block stuff goes here.
    </div>
    <div>
      Block stuff goes here.
    </div>
    <div>
      Block stuff goes here. 
    </div>
  </section>
```

I would also add probably classes to each so you can control those outer groupings individually.

The last thing I would do is learn to use flexbox, and apply the appropriate CSS to the outer section.

Hope I helped! :)

Comment: What would you recommend to build the orange block paragraphs?  I can tell based upon the layout, the divs are just doing to be on the page and not really part of the main

Comment: I'd use a div or `<section>` element for the entire group of them, but then each one would be in it's own div. I will add an edit example to my actual answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've done a lot of html/css classes online, but putting all the components together has been the difficult part.

Comment: It's understandable, I just want to see people learning to do it more or less right because a lot of the solutions I see are not even close to proper semantic markup.

Also to fix the jittering because of the border, apply it to the unhovered state, just make it the same color as the background so that it isn't noticeable.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joh03933/xjL3j8nr/26/  This is what Ive come up with, thanks for any feed back

Comment: You're welcome! I would even go so far as to have those headers inside the block containers so they align properly. Cheers!